# Server Block with 2 ports and 2 root directory's?

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    listen 27700;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /home/application/app_purple_code/admin/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        limit_req zone=one burst=8;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_buffering on;
        fastcgi_buffers 96 32k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

}

I have this server block above, but is there a way to use TWO ports for two different root folders.

So i want,
The default above and also another port with e.x

```
listen 28800;
```

and pointing to;

```
root /home/application/app_purple_code/admin2/;
```

....
I want to be able to go to `http://IP.com:27700` and `http://IP.com:28800`
so basically like having a official admin release on 1 port and a beta admin portal on the other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you just described here are two `server {}` blocks. So, to accomplish what you want, you have to create them individually, each one with a distinct `listen` and a `root` directives.

Here's an example:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/site1
# Be sure to run sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site1 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1 after you've created the file below
server {
    listen 28800;
    root /var/www/site1/public_html;
}

# /etc/nginx/sites-available/site2
# Be sure to run sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site2 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site2 after you've created the file below
server {
    listen 27700;
    root /var/www/site2/public_html;
}
```

After that, restart the Nginx service with `sudo nginx reload` or `systemctl restart nginx.service`.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you post an example, please? I tried and one worked the other didn't

Comment: Sure! Example added.